# Should I use in or at the corner?

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> Lying **in** the corner was the huge lion.
>
> Lying **at** the corner was the huge lion.

Is there any different in meaning?

Comment: You really should read through [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4821); it contains helpful information that, if followed, will lead to fewer updates by community members.

Answer (score 7):

An entity *in* the corner usually means it occupies an enclosed position **inside** the boundaries which define the corner:

            `__________
           |  x IN the corner of the room
           |
           |
           |`

An entity *at* the corner usually means it occupies an unenclosed position **outside** the boundaries.

        `x AT the corner of the street
            __________
           |
           |
           |
           |`

But an enclosed area within a larger enclosing area will usually be said to be *at* the corner of the enclosing area.

            `__________
           | x     |   IN the corner of the room AT the corner of the house
           |
           |_______|
           |`